# Problems with routing for multiple uplinks/providers

Tags: debian, iproute

My server has two internet connections: the first one (eth1) has a public IP, the second one (eth2) has a private IP because is connected to an ADSL modem.

I am trying to use both internet connections but I experimented some problems. Following the [LARTC How To](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html), I created my rules tables, set up the route tables and use load balancing for traffic going out over the two providers. Here is my script:

```
# do this once
echo -e "230\tnet1" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo -e "231\tnet2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip route add 10.250.0.1 dev eth2 src 10.250.0.2 table net2
ip route add XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dev eth1 src XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX table net1

ip route add default via 10.250.0.1 table net2
ip route add default via XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX table net1

ip rule add from 10.250.0.2 lookup net2
ip rule add from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX lookup net1

ip route add default scope global\
nexthop via XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dev eth1 weight 3\
nexthop via 10.250.0.2 dev eth2 weight 1
```

I do not use iptables for packet marking.

My problem is when I enable both links, I have lost packets. Using tcpdump I checked that there is no outgoing traffic. So I can't surf the web, send emails, and nothing. If I enable only one link, everything goes well.

My server is Debian 8. Output of the command **uname -a** gives me this:

```
3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```